# Optimal way to overcome inconsistency when storing two domain models (User) with same unique identifier ("username")

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, domain-driven-design

When creating users I want to avoid **duplicate usernames**.

Prior creating I am checking if username already exists to throw exception; however  **when user requests are executed in parallel my code won't prevent storing duplicate usernames.**

---

**Edited**

By the way I want to maintain consistency not in database but in application layer. I don't want to depend on specific database.

How do you think what will be optimal way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Prior creating I am checking if username already exists to throw exception; however when user requests are executed in parallel my code won't prevent storing duplicate usernames.

The general term for what you are trying to achieve is [set validation](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/08/12/eventual-consistency-and-set-validation/).

If you need to ensure that any change to a member of the set satisfies some invariant, then that implies that the set itself is a thing that you need to be able to load into memory.  So your domain model might include a User Registry entity, and all modifications to users pass through the registry.

When you are dealing with *uniqueness*, another possibility is to use the unique property itself as the primary key (either as a natural key, or a hash), then write your constraints such to ensure that you don't get two different users stored under the same key.

(Do users in your domain have multiple email addresses? do they change addresses?)

It might be that the mapping of an email address to a user is a separate relationship from the user itself.  Or that a user claiming to control an email address is a separate piece of information from *verifying* that the user controls that email address.

(In short, modeling information that your system controls differs from modeling information that some other system controls).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a relational data store, a unique constraint on the user name column will guarantee you can't store two users with the same user name.

Additionally, the check you perform could be transnational with the insert, so you check the name does not exist and store the new user within a single transaction.

On a human level, using email as a user name often makes it easier for people to remember their user name (rather than being Ako542 in one place and Ako392 in another). It is unlikely that two people would attempt to use it in parallel, thus making it unlikely they will see the message generated by the technical solutions provided above.

Comment: Thanks for response, it will actually work, but i want to maintain consistency in application layer, what do you think about this?

Answer (score 0):

It's better and easier to ensure uniqueness on db level, but if you absolutely must to do that on applicative level and uniqueness must be granted on service cluster level (between all running instances of the service, so working  with memory won't help) and you need solution for race condition, you can use distributed locking mechanism. Normally all MS ecosystems have component to provide locking functionality as service (Consul as example) but still it is bit more complex solution, and instead of being coupled to db the solution will be coupled to lock providing service.

Again, this is only relevant for very specific cases, and will help to avoid race condition problems during record creation between different instances of service on app level (the issue you described)